# Python to C/C++ const char question

Tags: python, c, const-char

I am extending Python with some C++ code.

One of the functions I'm using has the following signature:

```
int PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(PyObject *arg, PyObject *kwdict,
                                char *format, char **kwlist, ...);
```

(link: http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.2p2/ext/parseTupleAndKeywords.html)

The parameter of interest is kwlist. In the link above, examples on how to use this function are given. In the examples, kwlist looks like:

```
  static char *kwlist[] = {"voltage", "state", "action", "type", NULL};
```

When I compile this using g++, I get the warning:

```
warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
```

So, I can change the static char* to a static const char*. Unfortunately, I can't change the Python code. So with this change, I get a different compilation error (can't convert char** to const char**). Based on what I've read here, I can turn on compiler flags to ignore the warning or I can cast each of the constant strings in the definition of kwlist to char *. Currently, I'm doing the latter. What are other solutions?

Sorry if this question has been asked before. I'm new.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does `PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords()` expect to modify the data you are passing in? Normally, in idiomatic C++, a `const <something> *` points to an object that the callee will only read from, whereas `<something> *` points to an object that the callee can write to.

If `PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords()` expects to be able to write to the `char *` you are passing in, you've got an entirely different problem over and above what you mention in your question.

Assuming that `PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords` does not want to modify its parameters, the idiomatically correct way of dealing with this problem would be to declare kwlist as `const char *kwlist[]` and use `const_cast` to remove its const-ness when calling `PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords()` which would make it look like this:

```
PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(..., ..., ..., const_cast<char **>(kwlist), ...);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords() does not expect to modify kwlist. Your suggestion is helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is an accepted answer from seven years ago, but I'd like to add an alternative solution, since this topic seems to be still relevant.

---

If you don't like the `const_cast` solution, you can also create a write-able version of the string array.

```
char s_voltage[] = "voltage";
char s_state[] = "state";
char s_action[] = "action";
char s_type[] = "type";
char *kwlist[] = {s_voltage, s_state, s_action, s_type, NULL};
```

The `char name[] = ".."` copies the your string to a writable location.